# How to create and place input fields on a canvas via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-input

My game has several users logged in at once. An initial input field appears into which the number of 
users is typed, e.g., the number '3' would indicate that three users want to login.

In response to the number entered, I want C# script to then create input fields, one for each user to login.

The following code accepts a number at runtime, and then attempts to create input field objects. 
The initial input field (to accept the number) called 'nameInputField', is added manually using the unity editor ; it is a child to a canvas.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine ;
using UnityEngine.UI ;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems ;

public class LoginWindow : MonoBehaviour 
{
private InputField nameInputField = null; // Assign in editor
string placeHolderText ;
int NUsers ;
InputField[] IDField;

private void Start()
{       
    placeHolderText = nameInputField.placeholder.GetComponent<Text> ().text = "Number of users ...";
    InputField.SubmitEvent submitEvent = new InputField.SubmitEvent();
    submitEvent.AddListener(SubmitName); // Add listener to catch the submit
    nameInputField.onEndEdit = submitEvent;
}

private void SubmitName(string number)
{
    Int32.TryParse(number, out NUsers) ; // convert string to number
    IDField = new InputField[NUsers] ;
    Debug.Log ("IDField.Length = " + IDField.Length );
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUsers ; i++ ){
               // problems here !  reference to IDField[i] generates an error !
                    } // end 'for'
} // end SubmitName

} // end LoginWindow
```

The code appears to create an InputField array ; 
at runtime, if I enter '3', I get the message "IDField.Length = 3". 
But there is no sign of these input fields anywhere : in neither Hierarchy, Scene nor Game. 
Furthermore, any code that I put within the 'if' block, referencing the elements of 'IDField', 
generates the error message: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
For example, "Debug.Log (IDField[i].name);" will generate that error.

How can I create and place these input fields on the canvas at runtime ?

Comment: a good idea to get going, is start with one, a "model" and just `Instantiate` it

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me some idea of how and where I would do that within the code I posted? I had thought the line "IDField = new InputField[NUsers] ;" was enough .

Comment: Hi Pat, you care completely missing very basic knowledge about Unity. Unity works with instantiated `GameObject`.  There is utterly no connection to "normal" OO engineering where you can merely create a new class.  You will have to step back and learn about `Instantiate` with GameObjects (including but not limited to `UI` elements such as `Button`). You'll have to know about prefabs.  Once you can `Instantiate` with the best of them, you can move on to specifics about `Instantiate` with UI elements

Comment: google millions of pages http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html  http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/953022/view.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally, you must learn about `Instantiate` which is the absolutely fundamental process in game engines. (Game engines are frame based, transform based, and an "[ECS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system)"; it is not conventional OO).

Your question calls for a

## full  tutiorial on the basics of a game engine, which revolves around "Instantiate":

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/instantiate

, it is not really answerable in QA form.

For the record, following is some typical code to **Instantiate a UI element, in this example a Button**

```
public SoundButton exampleButton;
...

private void NewOnRight(SBB s)
    {
    GameObject nu = Instantiate(exampleButton.gameObject);
    nu.transform.SetParent(buttonsHolder, false);
    nu.SetActive(true);
    nu.name = s.soundCode;
    
    SoundButton nusb = nu.GetComponent<SoundButton>();
    
    nusb.Info = s;
    nusb.theStar.enabled = false;
    nusb.topColor = daBoss.TopColorFor(s);
    nusb.bottomColor = daBoss.BottomColorFor(s);
    }
```

As an additional complication, in that code I'm using Unity's layout system - ***so you do not see*** 100s of lines of code dealing with the size and positioning of the UI element. In real life you'll have to do all that.

You will have to among other things master Unity's reactive auto-layout system for UI

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/comp-UIAutoLayout.html

(you can find 100s of tutorials and videos), and/or, master manually positioning UI elements in code.

Comment: This is actually the first answer to this question on SO.

Comment: Thank you Joe. I am new to Unity and there are many holes in my grasp of it. You are definitely right ; I took your advice and placed the following command within my 'for loop' : IDField[i] = Instantiate(nameInputField) as InputField; Lo and behold, when I run the game and type '3' into my nameInputField, three cloned input fields appear! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: We are here to answer all your questions day and night!  Don't hesitate to post a NEW good question like this one.  (Most unity questions on here are total crap.)